# JSON schema validation with Map of string with Enum constraints

Tags: json, jsonschema

Requesting help with JSON Schema validation, below is sample JSON and Schema. I am trying to figure out how to specify "ppd" schema rule specifically "cfg" is a map of String, String and need to further restrict the entries of the key and value in this map by Enum definition i.e. allowed values for "inputDateTimeFormat" is a valid date time format so rule should encode if key is "inputDateTimeFormat" then allowed value is a pattern matching date time format and similarly if key is "valuemapping" then allowed values is pattern matching k=v (example below).

Could you please suggest a way to achieve this?

JSON Sample -

```
{
  "sm": [
    {
      "mid": "id-1",
      "ppd": [
        {
          "name": "cc-1",
          "cfg": {
            "columns": "v-1",
            "valueMapping": "B=01;S=02"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "cc-2",
          "cfg": {
            "columns": "v-2",
            "inputDateTimeFormat": "ddMMMyyyy_HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS",
            "outputDateTimeFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:Ss.SSSZ"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "cc-3",
          "cfg": {
            "columns": "v-3;v-4",
            "markers": "d=01"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON Schema :

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema",
  "id": "source-mappings-schema",
  "required": true,
  "properties": {
    "sm": {
      "type": "array",
      "id": "source-mappings-schema/sm",
      "required": true,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "id": "source-mappings-schema/sm/0",
        "required": true,
        "properties": {
          "mappingId": {
            "type": "string",
            "id": "source-mappings-schema/sm/0/mappingId",
            "required": true
          },
          "ppd": {
            "type": "array",
            "id": "source-mappings-schema/sm/0/ppd",
            "required": true,
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "id": "source-mappings-schema/sm/0/ppd/0",
              "required": true,
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "id": "source-mappings-schema/sm/0/ppd/0/name",
                  "required": true
                },
                "cfg": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "id": "source-mappings-schema/sm/0/ppd/0/cfg",
                  "required": true,
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with your schema contains a few issue.

The $schema tag is wrong, it should be

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
```

The 'required' property is supposed to be an array of property names that are required (not a bool), so you need to apply this at the level above.

Finally the validation of cfg. By specifying a schema for 'additionalProperties' you can provide validation rules for all unspecified key values (you said it was a map of strings, so I've set it to string, but you could also add other rules here like max length etc).
For the keys you know about you can add a property for each of them with the approrate validation rules (the rules i've added demonstrate the concept and will need tweaking for your use).

[image]

```
                       "cfg": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "additionalProperties": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "properties": {
                                    "inputDateTimeFormat": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "format": "date-time"
                                    },
                                    "valuemapping": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "pattern": "[a-z]\\=[a-z]"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```